# get selected li from url

Tags: jquery, html-lists, selected

I'm trying to add to my selected li the proper class if the li's selected html text match with the retrived url substring. To give an example 
I have the following list

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="">test</a></li>
 <li><a href="">test2</a></li>
 <li><a href="">test3</a></li>
</ul>
```

If I click on **test2** than a get parameter going to be passed and my url would look as it follows

```
localhost/page/test2
```

and after the second li should get  selected class.
What I tried but it's not working http://jsfiddle.net/lgtsfiddler/ZjNsv/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check each link in the UL against the variable you're looking for:

```
$("#tier_0").find("a").each(function() {

    if ($(this).text().match(variables[1])) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
    }

});
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZjNsv/8/

Comment: thanks a lot! Just on thing what is on my mind. Is the workaround what I chosed the proper one?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `url variables` - those are parametrs which you can send through url , exactly as you want, using the following format

assuming url is www.example.com/?class=3

then `$_GET["name"]`'s value is "3".
For further information read `http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php` . 
Then , you can mark a certain

by the parameter passed in the url.
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

in your example,
     'variables[1]' is "Notebooks".
You need to take 'variables[2]', for "#driver_explorer"

Comment: Yes there was a mistake in it. But anayway everytime the first li is going to get the selected class

Comment: in this line --> $j("ul #tier_0 li:eq(0)").addClass('selected');
you are selecting first li. Because you use ':eq(0)'.
If you want the second one, you should write ':eq(1)'.

Answer (score 0):

Would that be any of help?

```
$(function(){
    var current_url = "http://localhost/drivers/Notebooks/#driver_explorer";
    var variables = current_url.split('/');

    $('#tier_0 li a').click(function() {
        if ( $(this).html() == variables[variables.length-2] ) {
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        };
    });          
});
```

Replacing the current_url with whatever you have there, to make it dynamic....